# MYSQL, sort one table with the result of another table when they haven't the same number of columns

Tags: python, mysql

I'm designing a database for a market place. In a query, I call all the available products that satisfy my conditions.

```
SELECT products.product_id, suppliers.supplier_id, product_code.desc_fa, products.name_fa, MIN(product_supplier.price) AS price FROM products 
JOIN product_code ON product_code.code_id = products.code_id 
JOIN product_supplier ON product_supplier.product_id = products.product_id 
JOIN suppliers ON suppliers.supplier_id = product_supplier.supplier_id 
JOIN product_tags ON product_tags.product_id = products.product_id 
JOIN tags ON tags.tag_id = product_tags.tag_id 
JOIN product_crop ON product_crop.product_id = products.product_id 
JOIN crops ON crops.crops_id = product_crop.crop_id 
WHERE crops.crops_id = 1 AND product_supplier.quantity >= 3 AND tags.tag = 'علف کش'
GROUP BY products.name_fa 
LIMIT 10;
```

which shows me this result

[image]

I have another table with different purchase orders, which also include the location_id of the customers and sort the product_ids by the popularity of the products in a given location

```
SELECT orders.product_id FROM orders
JOIN user ON user.user_id = orders.user_id
WHERE user.location_id = 883 AND orders.crop_id = 1
GROUP BY orders.product_id
ORDER BY SUM(orders.quantity) DESC;
```

which shows me this result

[image]

What I want to do is to sort the first table by the popularity of the products in the second table for a given location_id, the problem is that the first table for example shows 4 viable products, but the second table based on the location_id only have 3 products, or in other word only 3 products have been bought so far in that area. 
My question is how to sort the table to show all the viable products, but the 3 bought (popular) products in that area to be shown first, and afterward the rest of the viable products. It has to be something like this but without the last part being hard coded.

```
SELECT products.product_id, suppliers.supplier_id, product_code.desc_fa, products.name_fa, MIN(product_supplier.price) AS price FROM products 
JOIN product_code ON product_code.code_id = products.code_id 
JOIN product_supplier ON product_supplier.product_id = products.product_id 
JOIN suppliers ON suppliers.supplier_id = product_supplier.supplier_id 
JOIN product_tags ON product_tags.product_id = products.product_id 
JOIN tags ON tags.tag_id = product_tags.tag_id 
JOIN product_crop ON product_crop.product_id = products.product_id 
JOIN crops ON crops.crops_id = product_crop.crop_id 
WHERE crops.crops_id = 1 AND product_supplier.quantity >= 3 AND tags.tag = 'علف کش'
GROUP BY products.name_fa 
ORDER BY FIELD(products.product_id, 106, 103, 101) DESC LIMIT 10;
```

[image]

if i use a join the first table with the order table, i only get 3 results at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can achieve the result using COALESCE + LEFT JOINS:

```
SELECT products.product_id,
       suppliers.supplier_id,
       product_code.desc_fa,
       products.name_fa,
       MIN(product_supplier.price) AS price,
       SUM(COALESCE(orders.quantity, 0)) AS n_orders
FROM products
JOIN product_code ON product_code.code_id = products.code_id
JOIN product_supplier ON product_supplier.product_id = products.product_id
JOIN suppliers ON suppliers.supplier_id = product_supplier.supplier_id
JOIN product_tags ON product_tags.product_id = products.product_id
JOIN tags ON tags.tag_id = product_tags.tag_id
JOIN product_crop ON product_crop.product_id = products.product_id
JOIN crops ON crops.crops_id = product_crop.crop_id
LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.product_id = products.product_id and orders.crop_id = product_crop.crop_id
LEFT JOIN user ON user.user_id = orders.user_id and user.location_id = 883
WHERE crops.crops_id = 1
  AND product_supplier.quantity >= 3
  AND tags.tag = 'علف کش'
GROUP BY products.name_fa 
ORDER BY n_orders DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Not sure about the `LEFT JOIN orders ON...` in the query for I don't know the exact relationship, but adding a left join will extract rows from the part of the query inherited for your first query even if there are no orders associated (for the hardcoded `location_id` in the join) and `COALESCE` let you sum NULL as if they are 0.

Comment: thanks for your answer, it is working, but there's a minor problem, the n_orders for the first item is showing 33, instead 11. for other products it shows the correct number, how should i solve for that ? there are 3 suppliers for that product_id and the code is supposes to show the cheapest one, could it be due to multiplying 11 by 3 and having 33 ??

Comment: Yes, I guess so. It0s probably because my "LEFT JOIN orders" do not uses supplier_id in the join so it triples the rows for each supplier. Try adding supplier_id in the join